# General solution differential equation with hint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently learning about differential equations, but I'm having trouble with finding the general solution with some of the harder problems:

$xdy-ydx = y^3(x^2+y^2)dy$

where it gives a "hint":

$d(tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$

I'm completely lost on how to start this problem!

Comment: do you expand $d(tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x})=\\ \frac{\frac{xdy-ydx}{(\frac{y}{x})^2}}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2}$?

Comment: All the question said was "Consider $d(tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d(tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x})=\ \frac{\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2}=\ \frac{xdy-ydx}{(x^2+y^2)}\\$$

after rearranging the D.E
$$ \frac{xdy-ydx}{(x^2+y^2)}=y^3dy\\$$
$$ \int d(tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}) =\int y^3dy$$
hence the solution is
$$\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}=\frac{y^4}{4}+C$$